# Getting rid of block like characters at the end of line in vim

Tags: vim, themes

[image]

Given my .vimrc, how do I get rid of these brownish characters at the end of line in vim ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be either the result of a previous search for `$` (end of line),
or the explicit display of end of line markers.

You can disable the highlighting of search results with `:set nohlsearch`.

You can disable the explicit end of line markers with `:set nolist`.

Answer (score 3):

If you actually want to remove the trailing whitespace:

```
:%s/[[:space:]]\+$//
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a function on my `~/.vimrc` file that I am used linking with my save routine`

```
fun! CleanExtraSpaces()
        let save_cursor = getpos(".")
        let old_query = getreg('/')
        :%s/\s\+$//e
        call setpos('.', save_cursor)
        call setreg('/', old_query)
 endfun
 com! Cls :call CleanExtraSpaces()

 " auto clean trailing spaces
 if has("autocmd")
    autocmd BufWritePre *.txt,*.js,*.py,*.wiki,*.sh :call CleanExtraSpaces()
 endif
```

This code gets rid of all exta spaces during saving or you can 
call it manually by typing `:Cls<Enter>`

the most important part is `:%s/\s\+$//e`

```
\s\+ .............. one space or mor
$ ................. at the end of the line
e ................. if not exists any extra space it ignores error messages
```